# how to forecast smaller balance sheet items

Tags: finance, financial-economics, corporate-finance

How might you forecast smaller line items on the balance sheet? For example like current liabilities, current portion of long-term debt or notes payable when doing a 3-statement model?

Would it be appropriate to use the figures of the most recent year for future year projections?